# How to load view containing data with ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel-4

I have Restful controller that renders a view with data from database and I want to load this view with its data in another view via ajax. There is a problem "undefined variable". Is there any solution?

Comment: please add some of your code. have a look [here for help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to share the code of your controller and more details about where the "undefined variable" error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass variables to your view they are only available on the server side while the view renders and then they are discarded. What this means is that the variables are only available to the php of your application and then they are gone by the time the view has been rendered and sent to the visitors web browser.

If you try to use the variables with JavaScript then you are running the JavaScript on the client side (as opposed to the server side). The variables that you pass to your view do not exist on the client side where your JavaScript runs.

From what it sounds like. You are defining a variable in your controller via laravel. Then you are passing the variable from the controller to the view. The view is then rendered as html and sent to the visitor's computer (the client) which the html is then loaded and that is when the JavaScript starts to load.

---

That's the problem, now possible solutions.

First you could send the variable (assuming it is simple data and not like an object) to the browser through laravel flash variables which are actually stored on one time cookies on the client side. Then you use JavaScript to access the cookie and get the data then storing it to a js variable and using it in your script.

Second you create an Api to respond to your http requests and then send an Ajax request from your JavaScript to the api to get the data. Then you would store it in JavaScript and use it. This allows complex data like objects because you would use the JSON format to send information to respond to the Ajax call. While cookies are restricted to (5kb I think) there is really no theoretical limit to JSON data.

I hope that helps and I hope I'm understanding your problem.

Comment: I have  implemented  second solution   and it is fine

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see your javascript before anything, but usually for me this means a misspelled element id or misspelled a reference file